Question about equivalent statements of Picard Theorem
I want to prove following (Big Picard Theorem forms):
Theorem.
The followings are equivalent:
a) If $f \in H(\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\})$ and $f(\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, 1\}$, then $f$ has a pole or an removable singularity at $0$.
b) Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a open subset, $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. If $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$, then, with at most one exception, $f$ attains every complex value infinitely many times;
c) Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ a entire function which is not polynomial. Then, with at most one exception, $f$ attains every complex value infinitely many times;
I have proved that a) $\implies$ b) $\implies$ c) and that b) $\implies$ a) but I don't know how to start proving that c) implies a) or b). And another thing: Is mathematically correct to say that those points are equivalent? I only want a hint or something that can make me understand how to start. Thanks! I see that in a) and b) I have a open set $\Omega$, but in c) I have the full complex plane, and I don't know how to reduce from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\Omega$
Edit: Here is a photo from the textbook (Page $358$):


$\mathbb{D}'$ is what? and what is your meaning of "$f$ has a pole of an removable singularity at $0$"? Could you give the source of your question?

@Riemann I've added an edit. The source of my question is from Complex Made Simple by David C. Ullrich. He says that Picard Great Theorem has these equivalent forms. He proved that a) and b) are equivalent and I want to see if these are equivalent to c)

@Riemann do you have any idea?

Theorem $20.2$ is equivalent to theorem $20.3$ and theorem $20.2$ implies theorem $20.1$.  Theorem $20.2$  is stronger that theorem $20.1$. You should read your textbook carefully!

@Riemann Stronger doesn't necessarily imply strictly stronger. I think OP is looking for a determination on the "strictness of the strength", so to speak.
